# I am trying to use the getline function in c++ but it keeps coming up with an error

Tags: c++, getline

This is the code.

[image]

I am trying to parce a line into a file using a colon as a delimeter from an input file.

Example of the input file line:

> Mike:Miller:1234:10.23:40

Comment: What is the error?  Please don't post images of code.  We can't feed an image into a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 2):

A string literal is a `const char[]`, which decays into a `const char*`. The 3rd parameter of `std::getline()` takes a single `char`, not a `const char*`. You need to change `”` to `’` in your literals, eg:

```cpp
getline(ss, firstName, ‘:’);
```